# Website Layout not functioning in Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

just like the title says, my website layout appears to be fine on all other browsers at various zooms, sizes and what not, but not in Safari.

The website adheres to HTML5 and CSS3 standards according to W3Cs validators, and I cannot spot any errors myself.

Website can be found at : http://www.kehza.co.uk/Arcade

It's very basic atm, I want the layout to work on all browsers before I progress. (catch bugs early on).

Edit :-

In Safari at certain zooms, massive white space appears at the bottom of the page, also a border is massively out of place.

See images for difference thanks :)

[image: Normal Site]
[image: Broken Site]
[image: Broken Site Screen 2]

Comment: It looks the same on all browsers (Safari, Chrome & Firefox) on Mac OS X. What is the expected result? Attach some screenshots please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The latest version of Safari for Windows is 5.1.7, but some of the CSS tags that you are using require Safari 7.0. One example is the box-shadow for the #wrapper element. This is why the website does not display correctly in the Windows version of Safari.

Source: http://caniuse.com/#search=webkit-box-shadow.

It is rumored that Apple has dropped development for Safari on Windows. You will probably want to decide what legacy version of Safari that the website will support. If you are planning on using features of CSS3, then you will want to test the website in a later version of the Safari browser, available on the OSX platform.

Comment: I see, it's probably one of my height parameters for content-wrapper which isn't compatible which would explain it, thanks for the information :)